# Unexpected duplicate result when creating all combinations for n bits

Tags: prolog

I need to learn Prolog for College, and gave myself a task to solve a single line of a Nonogram (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonogram).

I am using 'x' as 'o' as characters for a filled or an empty field, and a brute force approach to, as a first step, find every combination in that line, regardless of the Nomogram rules. This step is really the same as finding every combination of n bits, like 000 001 010 011 100 101 110 111 with n=3. I am going to weed out the matching combinations according to Nomogram rules afterwards, in fact I got this bit of code working already. This is surely not efficient, but I am glad I got this far.

If there is a very easy approach, to solve all options for a line, according to the rules for the line, in a "forward" approach opposed to this brute force approach, I would love to learn how this can be done. Rules would be something like (10, [4,3]) meaning the row has 10 places, and 2 groups of 4 and 3 blocks. But since this is "just for fun", don't bother much with writing it, please!

The code below works - but it finds every combination twice, and I cannot find out why. Any idea what makes it list everything twice? If there are mayor no-nos in that code (there are for sure!), please feel free to point them out. I am just a couple of hours into the language, and still try to "force" the style for implicit or object oriented languages, with little success :)

```
count_list([], 0). % Count Elements in a List
count_list([_|T], C) :- 
    count_list(T, C1),
    C is 1 + C1.

append_list(X, [], [X]). % Attach a new Element as first to a List
append_list(X, List, [X|List]).

zeichen(x).
zeichen(o).

nonoline_generator(N, PartIn, Line) :- % Add x and o to the combination, except the last one
    count_list(PartIn, C),
    N > C + 1,
    zeichen(X),
    append_list(X, PartIn, PartAppended),
    nonoline_generator(N, PartAppended, Line).
nonoline_generator(N, PartIn, Line) :- % Add the last x or o to the line
    count_list(PartIn, C),
    N =:= C + 1,
    zeichen(X),
    append_list(X, PartIn, Line).

% Usage:
nonoline_generator(2, [], Out).
% gives (well... all double, at the moment)
% [x,x]
% [x,o]
% [x,x]
% [x,o]
% [o,x]
% [o,o]
% [o,x]
% [o,o]
```

Thanks a lot for any comments!

Comment: `append_list/3`: The first clause is subsumed by the second. So this is definitely a source of redundancy. Otherwise, the best solution is to use [tag:clpfd]. And, instead of `count_list/2` use `length/2` - mucho más rápidamente

Comment: `nonoline_generator/3`: Both clauses start with the same goal, you could factor that out. Then, calling some predicate a generator is very impish (imperative-ish as you are used to it from COP - command oriented programming). Almost every predicate can be used as a generator, simply use the most general query. Say, for length/2: `length(L,N).` Finally, why not say `maplist(zeichen, Xs)` using [`library(maplist)`](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/sicstus/maplist.pl) - SICStus' own definition is broken due to the use of some ill-defined construct.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is fill in a list with x's or o's:

```
bits([]).
bits([x|Rest]) :- bits(Rest).
bits([o|Rest]) :- bits(Rest).
```

```
?- length(B, 3), 
   forall(bits(B), 
          format('~q~n', [B])).
[x,x,x]
[x,x,o]
[x,o,x]
[x,o,o]
[o,x,x]
[o,x,o]
[o,o,x]
[o,o,o]
```

Comment: What brings you here? From AKA EricGT.